# not all arguments converted during string formatting while trying to write a list to .txt file

Tags: python, list

I want to write a list to a .txt file, here's my list:

```
[('Visible', 'JJ'),
 ('Landscape', 'NN'),
 ('Landscape', 'NN'),
 ('characteristics', 'NNS'),
 ('derived', 'VBN'),
 ('from', 'IN'),
 ('satellite-tracking', 'JJ'),
 ('data', 'NNS'),
 ('of', 'IN'),
 ('wintering', 'VBG'),
 ('habitats', 'NNS'),
 ('used', 'VBN'),
 ('by', 'IN'),
 ('oriental', 'JJ'),
 ('honey', 'NN'),
 ('buzzards', 'NNS'),
 ('in', 'IN'),
 ('Borneo', 'NNP')]
```

Here's my code to write that list:

```
with open('result.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.writelines("%s\n" % item for item in list)
```

But somehow it shows a following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-8d6e1711d648> in <module>()
      3 
      4 with open('cobahasil1.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
----> 5     filehandle.writelines("%s\n" % kata for kata in merged)

<ipython-input-47-8d6e1711d648> in <genexpr>(.0)
      3 
      4 with open('cobahasil1.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
----> 5     filehandle.writelines("%s\n" % kata for kata in merged)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: `filehandle.writelines("%s\n" % item for item in list)` Just a tip, don't use `list` as identifier

Comment: In general don't use ```reserved keywords```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in the iteration is a `tuple` with 2 elements.

So you just need to extract all elements:

```
tuples_list = [('Visible', 'JJ'),
 ('Landscape', 'NN'),
 ('Landscape', 'NN'),
 ('characteristics', 'NNS'),
 ('derived', 'VBN'),
 ('from', 'IN'),
 ('satellite-tracking', 'JJ'),
 ('data', 'NNS'),
 ('of', 'IN'),
 ('wintering', 'VBG'),
 ('habitats', 'NNS'),
 ('used', 'VBN'),
 ('by', 'IN'),
 ('oriental', 'JJ'),
 ('honey', 'NN'),
 ('buzzards', 'NNS'),
 ('in', 'IN'),
 ('Borneo', 'NNP')]

with open('result.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.writelines("%s %s\n" % item for item in tuples_list)
```

Comment: Sorry, i didnt' tell that i already store that list on a variable named **merged**

So, here's my actual code:
`with open('result.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    filehandle.writelines("%s\n" % item for item in merged)`

Comment: @pangestuf you are good to go, just change ```tuples_list``` to ```merged```